# Can we say "you can [not go] to school" or does it automatically become a negative sentence?

Tags: grammar, negation, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, negative-polarity-items

> "You can [not go] to school."

Can this sentence mean that you can stay here and not go, or does it automatically become a negative sentence if I say it like this?

Comment: Every sentence with a "not" in it is negative. I suppose you are really asking if "can not" means the same as "cannot". To which the answer is no, it does not. But for best results, you'll remove all confusion altogether by rewording. "You are free not to go to school." Or whatever.

Comment: If you say "*You can not go to school*", or *cannot*, or *can't*, it means you are prohibited from going to school (in previous decades, we used to reserve *can* for ability and *may* for permission, but that distinction has faded over the years, and now *may* has almost disappeared from contemporary American English). The sentence says nothing about what you *can* do. It gives no license for skipping school, and no invitation to stay home. It's a command.

Comment: You can change it from a command to a suggestion by adding "if you prefer" to it, such as "if you prefer, you can not go to school", or "You can not go to school if you prefer.", or even "You can, if you prefer, not go to school."  That has the effect of separating the "can" from the "not" and gives the ability (can) to not do something (not).

Comment: @RegDwigнt oxforddictionaries.com defines `cannot` as a contraction of `can not`. Would you mind to explain the difference?

Comment: "cannot" and "can't" are a definite "You are unable (or not allowed) to do this".  "can not" can be either "You can't do this", or "You have the ability to abstain from doing this" - a subtle but distinct difference depending on context.

Comment: It's all dependent on whether the vocal stress is on the "can" or the "not".  "You *can* not go to school" or "You can *not* go to school".

Comment: DUPLICATE of 'Is “can not” unambiguous?'

Comment: @RegDwigнt ***Every sentence with a "not" in it is negative***  - not so old bean. See my answer below ... :)

Comment: @FF I'm only allowed a certain number. And there's a lot of it about.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. You can not go to school.

It's perfectly possible to use the sentence above to mean that not going to school is a possible option. Notice that usually the word *cannot* is written as one word. This anomaly is probably not an accident. Usually if we have an auxiliary that is not contracted with the negative word *not*, the auxiliary is not stressed, the stress falls on the word *not*. Notice that this isn't the case when we say *cannot*. The stress here falls on the first syllable, in other words on the auxiliary:

- You **cann**ot go to school.

Compare this with, for example, with *have*:

- I've **not** finished yet.
- I have **not** finished yet.

When there's no contraction, the stress is standardly applied to the negative particle *not*; not to the auxiliary.

Now if we wish to negate the following verb instead of the auxiliary *can*, so that we mean that there's an option to **not** do something, all we need to do is stress the word *not* instead of the word *can*:

- You can ***not*** go.

Now if  we were very strict about writing *cannot* as one word instead of two, then we would not need to use italics when we were writing such sentences to indicate the stress here. We could just use two words *can not*. However, we aren't all that strict about it at all, and so in order to not be misunderstood it is probably best to use italics when writing to highlight the marked pronunciation.

Now, the Original Poster wisely asked if using a sentence like the above will negate the whole sentence instead of just the verb *go*. The answer is that it won't. We might think that the sentence is negated, purely on the basis of the lexical verb being negated. This isn't the case. We can do a test here to establish the polarity of the sentence. Usually a negative sentence will take a positive question tag and vice versa:

- You've eaten it, haven't you? (positive sentence, negative tag)
- You haven't seen it, have you? (negative sentence, positive tag)

If we stick a tag on a normal sentence where *can* is negated we will see a positive tag:

- You can't do it, can you? (negative sentence, positive tag)

However, if we negate the lexical verb *do* in this example, instead, by using marked stress, then we get the following result:

- You can *not* do it though, can't you?

Here we see a negative tag, which is a clear sign that the sentence has a positive polarity when the lexical verb is negated.

Of course this is one option open to a writer, if the genre and style aimed for will allow it. They can just stick a tag on the question:

- You can not go, can't you!

Arguably, however, it might still be best to use italics here to prevent the reader from having to reread the sentence.

Comment: +1, nice post! :) . . . aside: There might be a post somewhere on the differences between "can't" and "cannot" and "can not"; though not sure if it is on one of these sites.

Comment: Maybe also: *"You [can not] go to school, can you?"* and *""You can [not go to school], can't you?"*. And there's also: *"You cannot [not go to school], can you?"*

Comment: @F.E. Yes, that last ones interesting ... but I might be too tired to do it... :) But you could edit it in if you'd like! :D

Answer (score 2):

With suitable prosody, "You can not go to school" could mean "You are able not to go to school". But it is ambiguous, and without special stress it would probably be interpreted as "You cannot go to school".